# VB.NET DLL import works for a set number of times then gives false reading

Tags: vb.net, dll

I have an issue with my vb.net code...

I have created a C++ .dll file which returns 0 when the WiFi is disabled. This code works perfectly for 20 loops through, then gives me a false reading after then. It's almost as if it does not unload the dll file each time and something blocks it after 20 process spawns.

```
Imports System.Media
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Module Module1
    <DllImport("C:\Dll2.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
    Friend Function Helloworld(
         ByVal i As Int32) As Int32
    End Function


    Sub Main()

        While (1 = 1)
            Dim A
            A = Helloworld(5)
            Console.WriteLine(A)

            If A = 0 Then
                WiFi_Disabled()
            End If

            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

        End While
    End Sub

    Public Function WiFi_Disabled()
        Dim speech
        speech = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
        speech.speak("Please Turn your Wifi Back on")
    End Function

End Module
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Can you post the source for the c++ dll so I can try reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hi @preciousbetine i've worked out what the issue is. i'll update this thread with the solution. Thanks for offering your help

Comment: Ok! please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out that my .dll file was causing the error. It was all because i was not closing my WiFi handler. After 20 instances had been spawned, a memory error occurred. I needed to use this function to close the handler.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlanclosehandle